# Pie chart with color shades using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I possess a dataframe named "metadata" that contains information for cancer cohort samples. In this dataframe, the sample names are designated as row names. The type of cancer for each sample is listed under the "Cancer_Type" column, while the source dataset for each sample is noted in the "dataset" column. This data encompasses four distinct cancer types. I'd like a pie chart visualizing these four cancer types, with each type colored respectively: "red", "blue", "green", and "orange". Additionally, each cancer type should be further segmented based on the number of datasets it's associated with and the number of samples in each dataset. For example, if "Melanoma" appears in five datasets, its section on the pie chart should feature five distinct shades of its main color. The size of each shade should correlate with the sample count from its respective dataset. How can I accomplish that, using ggplot2 ?

Here is an example metadata, this is not the real data but it is similar:

```
structure(list(Cancer_Type = c("Melanoma", "Melanoma", "NSCLC", 
"NSCLC", "NSCLC", "Urothelial", "Urothelial", "Urothelial", "Urothelial", 
"Melanoma", "Melanoma", "RCC", "RCC", "RCC", "Urothelial", "Urothelial", 
"Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", 
"NSCLC", "NSCLC"), dataset = c("Dataset1", "Dataset1", "mydata2", 
"mydata2", "mydata2", "dataset3", "dataset3", "dataset3", "dataset3", 
"Data4", "Data4", "Dataset5", "Dataset5", "Dataset5", "Dataset6", 
"Dataset6", "Dataset7", "Dataset7", "Dataset7", "Dataset7", "Dataset7", 
"Dataset7", "Dataset8", "Dataset8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("X123", 
"PAT1", "PAT2", "pat32", "pat8", "pat12", "x1234", "x123456", 
"PAT90", "pat98", "p76", "op1", "p223", "P89", "p45", "p18", 
"P92", "PAT27", "PAT192", "PX123", "PX333", "p234", "p665", "p100"
))
```

**EDIT** - This code produces a classic pie chart with a different color for each cancer type, I hoped this would create the shades and cancer sub grouping but it didn't:

```
counts = metadata %>%
  group_by(Cancer_Type, dataset) %>%
  summarise(count=n())

cancer_colors = c("Melanoma"="red", "RCC"="blue", "NSCLC"="green", "Urothelial"="orange")
counts$main_color <- cancer_colors[counts$Cancer_Type]

counts <- counts %>%
  group_by(Cancer_Type) %>%
  mutate(fill = colorRampPalette(c(main_color, "white"))(n()))

ggplot(counts, aes(x = factor(1), y = count, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Pie chart of Cancer Types")
```

Comment: I suggest https://r-graph-gallery.com/pie-plot.html is a good place to learn how to do this.

Comment: @r2evans I always check there, but I didn't find anything about shading colors or sub grouping the different pie parts according to data set size..

Comment: Okay, some thoughts while I'm looking at it: it looks like you want to define literal colors, did you notice though that the colors used don't match what you define? That's because ggplot2 is treating `"#FFFFFF"` as a category, not a true color. Either use `fill = I(fill)` or map to the group itself and use `scale_fill_manual(values = ...)` (where the arg is a vector of colors with categories as their names). This is why your `"#ffffff"` is not white.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining the colors yourself, it is usually easier to use the scale functions appropriately. Similarly, we don't have to do the counts ourselves. One easy way to get different shades of the same color, is to use alpha transparency to fade to white.

We just need to define the datasets differently, so they are defined within each cancer type:

```
metadata %>% 
  group_by(Cancer_Type) %>% 
  mutate(dataset_nr = factor(dataset) %>% as.numeric() %>% as.factor()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = 1, fill = Cancer_Type, alpha = dataset_nr)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.3, 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cancer_colors) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

Do note that people usually have a hard time estimating the size of the slices of pie charts with many categories, and barplots may be a better option.

[image]

Comment: if I could `+2`, I would

Answer (score 2):

Although using the alpha scale would be the typical way to do this, I think a bespoke color palette using interactions gives you more control over the appearance. For a pie chart with a small number of slices, I think this is reasonable.

Some on-plot labelling is probably going to help too:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(counts, aes(x = factor(1), y = count)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = interaction(count, Cancer_Type)),
           width = 1, position = position_fill(), color = 'gray20') +
  geom_textpath(aes(label = paste0(dataset,  ' (n = ', count, ')'),
                    group = factor(dataset, dataset)), 
                position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_textpath(data = . %>% group_by(Cancer_Type) %>% 
                  summarize(count = sum(count)),
                aes(label = Cancer_Type, group = Cancer_Type), 
                position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), angle = 90,
                vjust = 6.2, size = 7.5) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Pie chart of Cancer Types") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`2.Melanoma` = '#f03232', 
                               `6.Melanoma` = '#f01515',
                               `3.RCC` = '#6364a6',`3.NSCLC` = '#718064', 
                               `2.NSCLC` = '#97aa84',
                               `4.Urothelial` = '#f79526', 
                               `2.Urothelial` = '#ffb025'))
```

[image]